# How do I use Autofixture (v3) with ICustomization, ISpecimenBuilder to deal with constructor parameter?

Tags: unit-testing, autofixture

I'm trying to overcome a scenario in which a class has a string constructor parameter which cannot be satisfied by any old string generated by Autofixture (the Guid-y looking value).

Before you're tempted to answer simply with a link to [Mark Seemann's Ploeh blog entry on Convention-based Customizations](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/19/Convention-basedCustomizationswithAutoFixture/), let me say that I've been referencing it and other blog entries of his for this test, which I can't get to pass.

When I step through in debug, I can see that at some point the constructor parameter is passed in with the valid value, but the test still fails with the Guid-y Color value.  I think this has something to do with the fact that there is both a 'color' parameter value, *and* a 'Color' property to be populated by Autofixture.  Is it that I've written an ISpecimenBuilder that addresses the constructor parameter, but I'm testing the public property value (two different things)?

I know that all this is overkill for the example, but I envision a more complicated scenario in which using the `Build<T>().With()` method would not be DRY.

**The Failing Test**

```cs
    [Fact]
    public void Leaf_Color_Is_Brown()
    {
        // arrange
        var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new LeafColorCustomization());

        // act
        var leaf = fixture.Create<Leaf>();

        // using .Build<>.With(), test passes
        //var leaf = fixture.Build<Leaf>().With(l => l.Color, "brown").CreateAnonymous();

        // assert
        Assert.True(leaf.Color == "brown");
    }
```

**The SUT**

```cs
    public class Leaf
    {
        public Leaf(string color)
        {
            if (color != "brown")
                throw new ArgumentException(@"NO LEAF FOR YOU!");

            this.Color = color;
        }
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }
```

**The CompositeCustomization implementation** (I know the AutoMoqCustomization() isn't needed in this example)

```cs
    public class LeafCustomization : CompositeCustomization
    {
        public LeafCustomization()
            : base(
            new LeafColorCustomization(),
            new AutoMoqCustomization()) { }
    }
```

**The Leaf-specific ICustomization**

```cs
    public class LeafColorCustomization : ICustomization
    {
        public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
        {
            if (fixture == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("fixture");

            fixture.Customizations.Add(new LeafBuilder());
        }
    }
```

**The String-constructor-with-name-of-Color-specific ISpecimenBuilder**

```cs
    public class LeafBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
    {
        public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
        {
            var pi = request as ParameterInfo;
            if (pi == null)
                return new NoSpecimen(request);

            if (pi.ParameterType != typeof(string) || pi.Name != "color")
                return new NoSpecimen(request);

            return "brown";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solution 1**:

Register that the `Color` writable property should not be assigned any automatic value as part of the post-processing:

```cs
internal class LeafColorCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<Leaf>(c => c
            .Without(x => x.Color));

        fixture.Customizations.Add(new LeafBuilder());
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**:

Make the `Color` property read-only:

```cs
public class Leaf
{
    private readonly string color;

    public Leaf(string color)
    {
        if (color != "brown")
            throw new ArgumentException(@"NO LEAF FOR YOU!");

        this.color = color;
    }

    public string Color
    {
        get { return this.color; }
    }
}
```

Since the `Color` property is read-only AutoFixture is not going to assign a value for it.

> The above solutions apply also to AutoFixture 2.

Comment: brilliant - that works! Re: Solution #1, could/should it be specified to skip the `Color` writable property inside the `ISpecimenBuilder` (`LeafBuilder`) rather than inside the `ICustomization` (`LeafColorCustomization`)? My impression is that many of these `.Without()` caveats would pollute the implementation, and that it would be cleaner (particularly in a more complex example) to have nothing but a series of `fixture.Customizations.Add(new XXXBuilder());` inside the `ICustomization` - am I not understanding where different customizations belong?

Comment: @Lumirris You could definitely handle the issue from within `LeafBuilder`. You'd just need to also handle the case where `request` is a `PropertyInfo` in addition to the case you already handle where it's a `ParameterInfo`.

Comment: @MarkSeemann - [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it) issues notwithstanding, is it preferable to handle from within the `ISpecimenBuilder` implementation `LeafBuilder` when considering more complex scenarios, using the `ICustomization` implementation to merely add all necessary `ISpecimenBuilder` implementations?

Comment: In this particular case, I'd definitely use an `ISpecimenBuilder` like `LeafBuilder` because it enables you to implement fine-grained, convention-based heuristics. OTOH, it's more work than using the strongly typed methods exposed by `IFixture`, so I use those if I can express what I want in that way.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you deal with the property setting stuff separately, here's a constructor argument restriction `Customization` which does the trick:

```cs
class BrownLeavesCustomization : ICustomization
{
    void ICustomization.Customize( IFixture fixture )
    {
        Func<string> notBrownGenerator = fixture.Create<Generator<string>>()
            .SkipWhile( x => x == "Brown" )
            .First;
        fixture.Customizations.Add( 
            ArgumentGeneratorCustomization<Leaf>.ForConstructorArgument(
                "color", 
                notBrownGenerator ) );
    }

    static class ArgumentGeneratorCustomization<T>
    {
        public static ISpecimenBuilder ForConstructorArgument<TArg>( string argumentName, Func<TArg> generator )
        {
            return new ConstructorArgumentGenerator<TArg>( argumentName, generator );
        }

        class ConstructorArgumentGenerator<TArg> : ISpecimenBuilder
        {
            readonly string _argumentName;
            readonly Func<TArg> _generator;

            public ConstructorArgumentGenerator( string argumentName, Func<TArg> generator )
            {
                Assert.Contains( argumentName, from ctor in typeof( T ).GetConstructors() from param in ctor.GetParameters() select param.Name );
                _argumentName = argumentName;
                _generator = generator;
            }

            object ISpecimenBuilder.Create( object request, ISpecimenContext context )
            {
                var pi = request as ParameterInfo;
                if ( pi == null )
                    return new NoSpecimen( request );
                if ( pi.Member.DeclaringType != typeof( T ) )
                    return new NoSpecimen( request );
                if ( pi.Member.MemberType != MemberTypes.Constructor )
                    return new NoSpecimen( request );
                if ( pi.ParameterType != typeof( TArg ) )
                    return new NoSpecimen( request );
                if ( pi.Name != _argumentName )
                    return new NoSpecimen( request );

                return _generator();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis Real reason I have this here is to see if it can provoke a reaction from you et al :) Know of any similar constructs in AF itself or publically available? Any ideas for improvement?

Answer (score 3):

Solution: (based on Mark Seemann's [comment on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15534718/533958))

Accommodate both the constructor parameter and the writeable property in the ISpecimenBuilder implementation, and do nothing other than add the LeafBuilder instance in LeafColorCustomization:

```cs
public class LeafBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var paramInfo = request as ParameterInfo;
        if (paramInfo != null
            && paramInfo.ParameterType == typeof(string)
            && paramInfo.Name == "color")
        { return "brown"; }

        var propInfo = request as PropertyInfo;
        if (propInfo != null
            && propInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string)
            && propInfo.Name == "Color")
        { return "brown"; }

        return new NoSpecimen(request);
    }
}

internal class LeafColorCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customizations.Add(new LeafBuilder());
    }
}
```